# i have created purchase.php page and showed the customer purchases detailes but now i want to delete the detailes when customer logout

Tags: php

```
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$q="select * from purchase where name='$name'";
$qs=mysqli_query($con,$q);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qs))
{
?>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img src="<?php echo $r['p_img'];?>" width="200px" height="200px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label>Product Name:</label><?php echo $r['p_name']; ?>
<div>
<label>Cost:</label><?php echo $r['p_cost'];?>
</div>
<div>
<label>Quntity:</label><?php echo $r['p_qun'];?>
</div>
<label>Product Detailes:</label><?php $arr=explode(".",$r['p_detailes']);
     foreach($arr as $a)
     {
        echo $a;?><br><?php
     }
    ?>
   </div>
 <?php
 }
?>
 </div>
```

this is my purchase.php page
i have created purchase.php page and showed the customer purchases detailes but now i want to delete the detailes when customer logout.

Comment: you mean you want delete the session data ? if it is use unset($_SESSION['name']);

Comment: i did not create session i don't know where to create session for this

Comment: $_SESSION['name']  show the login user name on top

Comment: if your not setting session means then how you used this *$name=$_SESSION['name'];*

Comment: i have create session for name only which is from another tabel which is register table and this info come from purchase table.

Answer (score -1):

Just run UPDATE SQL:

```
$q="UPDATE purchase SET detailes='' where name='$name'";
```

Comment: can you please explain this SET detailes means

Comment: That is for update statement. You can set a new value for fild detailes. You can find more detalis in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: In case you are new in SQL - W3SCHOOLS is best plase to learn.

Comment: actually what happen when same customer login again the purchase page display the all his purchase but i want to do page empty when customer logout.and when customer login again only new purchases want to display

Comment: Oh... then you must delete this entry from table by:
$q="DELETE FROM purchase where name='$name'";

Comment: yes but how becuase logout is link when customer click on logout after that i want to delete record. so for that i have to give any condition??

Comment: What happens when client click on this link? 
I think that this looks like that <a href="?logout">Logout</a>
Then you must write in PHP
<?php
if(isset($_GET['logout']){
$q="DELETE...";
/ remove all session variables
session_unset();
// destroy the session
session_destroy(); 
}
Regarding sessions you can find more - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

?>

Comment: Please check DB after logout. Do the necessary entry is deleted?

Comment: from database entry not deleted i checked database also

Comment: <?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$q="delete from purchase where name='$name'";
$qs=mysqli_query($con,$q);
unset($_SESSION['name']);
}
header("location:index.php");
exit;
?>                                                                                                                    this is my logout page

Comment: Then serch why if(isset($_GET['logout']) doesn't works.
You can chek it by:
if(isset($_GET['logout']){
   echo "WORKS"!
}

Comment: problem solve. no need to add if statement direct execute the delete query on logout.php page. thank you so much for help